# How to filter location based tweets in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, geolocation

I'm using a simple bot that favorite tweets based on keywords. I'd like to only favorite tweets from a specific location. Any idea how to do this in ruby? If not possible in ruby I'm open to other languages. Thanks

My code:

```
require 'twitter' #gem install twitter

while true
begin
    config = {
        consumer_key: 
        consumer_secret:
        access_token: 
        access_token_secret:
    }

    rClient = Twitter::REST::Client.new config
    sClient = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new(config)

    # topics to watch
    topics = ['star wars']
    sClient.filter(:track => topics.join(',')) do |tweet|
        if tweet.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
          puts tweet.text 
          rClient.fav tweet
        end
    end
rescue Exception => e
    puts 'error, waiting for 5s: ' + e.class.to_s
    sleep 5
end
end
```

I tried to add these lines but it doesn't work (for NYC lat/long):

```
    @Geo = Twitter::Geo.new(coordinates: [22.2798024,114.149884])
    sClient.filter(:track => topics.join(','), :Geo => Tweet.Geo('40.7033127,-73.979681')) do |tweet|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter based on locations you need the location parameter in the hash.

So, this is how your filter function call should look like

```
sClient.filter(:track => topics.join(','), :locations => "40.7033127,-73.979681") do |tweet|
```

Thats it and you are good to go. I found it in [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Streaming/Client#filter-instance_method) and in this [example](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Streaming.md).

Comment: do you know how to make this such that it only filters tweet from the location AND the topics (currently it's filter tweets EITHER from the location OR from the topics)? thanks

Comment: Try this sClient.filter(options = {:track => topics.join(','), :locations => "40.7033127,-73.979681"} ) do |tweet|

Comment: sorry this doesn't work actually. It still shows location OR topics, not both